# How can I parse this URL in google sheets to just show price?

Tags: regex, api, parsing, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How could I use the "importdata" function in google sheets with this URL to parse the data from the URL and just show the price in a cell?

https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=samoyedcoin&vs_currencies=usd

Here is an example of what I am looking to do, just with the above URL

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(IMPORTDATA("https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/ETH-USD/ticker"),0,2), "price:",""), """", ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTDATA(A1), "\d+.\d+|\d+")*1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION:

You can also try using a combination of [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) & [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(IMPORTDATA("https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/ETH-USD/ticker"),"Select Col2"),"price:""(.*)""")
```

### Sample

[image]